# How to remove Only HTML tags in the program

Tags: c#, html

I want to remove HTML Tags with some source with C#.

Unfortunately, there are some content like <This is content>

first, I tried to Regex class like that.

```
Regex.Replace(htmltext,"[\\x00-\\x1f<>:\"/\\\\|?*]" +
        "|^(CON|PRN|AUX|NUL|COM[0-9]|LPT[0-9]|CLOCK\\$)(\\.|$)" +
        "|[\\. ]$", String.Empty);
```

but in this case,
 "<This is content>" was removed.

so anyone, please tell me how to remove Only HTML Tags in the program.

Thanks regard.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and parse HTML with Regex. [It tends not to go well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Use a parser, [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) is very popular.

Using HTML agility pack you can simply call [`InnerText`](https://html-agility-pack.net/inner-text) to extract the contents without HTML tags.